# Dax measure to highlight the difference between slicers

Tags: dax, measure

I have a Power BI report that should highlight the difference of ETA column ( see below) by the comparison of 2 snap dates (if the ETA value changes from the date of the first selected date in the slicer, in comparison to the second slicer, the ETA cell should be colorized). I need a DAX measure that would help me do that

[image: The Concept]

[image: The Concept]

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what you expect the result to look like. Can you mock up your intended end result?

Comment: I need each Eta cell to be colored if the value of eta changes from one date from another, for instance if the first snapdate cell has the date of 10th December, and for 10th of December i have the eta of 4 January, the change of snapdate in 11th of December might bring a different eta, for the same eta cell, if there's a difference, i need it to be colorized